# error NG8001: 'ion-list' is not a known element: Ionic v7

Tags: ionic-framework

Following are the steps i have taken

1. I created a new project of ionic 7 using ionic start template blank
2. updated angular to angular 17.3
3. created a new page module of home

i am getting following error
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXv8R.png)

Following is the code

[main.ts code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQI5L.png)

[app.routes.ts code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmLNC.png)

[home.page.ts code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcJ5k.png)

[home.page.html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcuiR.png)

`ionic start`

Comment: Please edit your question to [include code, data and error messages as text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16563198).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have not imported `IonItem` as the rest of the components, hence the error. With standalone ionic components, all used components must be imported.

It's weird you also have the error about the `ion-list`component, since your import statement looks correct.